# How to style a button on disabled state using inline CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a button and I want to style it when disabled using **inline** style only.

I know how to style using internal/external style.

Code below:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: It's not possible, but you can add a `<style></style>`-block to add the CSS needed if you have control over the surrounding HTML.

Comment: @Emil, I know other ways but this. I wanted to know if it is possible using inline CSS anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Other than by explicitly changing the style with JavaScript (which violates your "inline CSS only" constraint): you can't.

The style attribute only contains the *body* of a rule-set. It can't do anything that you need a selector for.

Comment: sorry to say but i think this should be comment as op did not ask is it possible and you are saying that this is not possible.